# jmeter user accounts versus threads

Tags: load, automated-tests, jmeter

I am just starting to use jmeter and I had a question I have not been able to find the answer to:

Is the thread the same as a user?

The reason I ask is that I have a webpage that requires a username/password.  If I use one username and password during the recording of my steps, but then during testing run with say 50 threads - is this simulating 50 users or just the one?

Do I need to create 50 test user accounts to properly test this? I know I can use variables and the various controls within jmeter to do this, but what I need to understand is this something that is required.

And, if I do not need to create 50 users, why not?  Seems that all the threads would be using the same session information - or does that not come into play?

Comment: Any feedback on this?

Answer (score 2):

In JMeter 1 User = 1 Thread

Yes you must have 50 test user accounts to be realistic.

[CSV_Data_Set_Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) is the component to look at for variables.

You understand well, 50 threads using 1 account => TOTALLY WRONG AND UNREALISTIC :-)